# Having problem to desctructure my data on React

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

The `upcomingWork` contains my apis data. What I want here is to insert this as an array to display it on my calendar, below are the example of structured data I want.

Actually, the `upcomingWork` contains a lot of attributes but I just want to get those three attributes to display on my calendar.

```
const data = upcomingWork.map(u => u.id && u.title && u.created_at);
```

Example of array that I want to create from `data`.

```
  const events = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'My event',
      start: new Date(2020, 4, 8, 10, 0),
      end: new Date(2020, 4, 8, 14, 0),
    },
  ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map that you have will simply set every value to either true if all values are truey or false if any of them are falsey. if you want to extract those 3 values just change the map to this:

```
const data = upcomingWork.map(({id, title, created_at}) => ({id, title, created_at}))
```

Comment: Just a follow up all your answers are correct but I follow this code. Can I format my dates before it will pass down to my array using `Moment`. But the start only gives me an `undefined value`

const data = upcomingWork.map(u => ({
      id: u.id,
      title: u.title,
      start: Moment(u.created_at.format('yyyy mm dd hh m')),
      end: u.created_at,
 }));

Comment: is the created_at a moment object already? if not .format would just call an undefined function on a string? `Moment(u.created_at, "yyyy mm dd hh mm")` would be the way to do it if `created_at` is a string

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you returned is not going to give you any desired data. 
I think you misunderstood the map method of Array.

Instead you should use map like:

```
const data = upcomingWork.map(u => {
             const {id, title, created_at} = u;
                 return {
                   id,
                   title,
                   created_at
                 }
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = upcomingWork.map(u => {
    return { id: u.id, title: u.title };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `upcomingWork.map` doesn't create an object at all, so it has no chance of creating the expected data. Instead, you can map appropriate properties of the `u` object to the new keys in a new object you create.

```
const events = upcomingWork.map(u => ({
    id: u.id,
    title: u.title,
    start: u.created_at,
    end: u.end    //change the u.end to whatever property you have in your data
}));
```

(the new object has to be wrapped in () to ensure JS interprets it as a value, not a function body)